# IE8 add embed element to object element

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am experiencing an issue on IE8 when trying to add embed element as a child to the object element, via JavaScript.

I am using an usual combination of createElement and appendChild. However, I get an "Invalid argument" error. This error does not occur when trying to add to other elements, at least to those that I have tested so far.

It looks like a browser bug to me, but I might be mistaken. Has anybody experienced this problem before and is there some other solution beyond hacking with innerHTML?

I am using it on XP SP3, browser mode IE8, document mode IE8 Standards.

Here is the code:

```
o = document.createElement('object')
document.body.appendChild(o)
e = document.createElement('embed')
o.appendChild(e)
```

Comment: I update the post with the code, if anybody finds it useful. I omitted the attributes like src, height, and width, since error occurs either way.

Comment: "It looks like a browser bug to me" Have you tested the results on another browser?

Comment: Yes, it works on Firefox 9, the latest version of Chrome, and IE9 if I recall correctly. Those are the browsers I tested so far.

Comment: I can solve the issue by setting the altHtml attribute to desired HTML value for the embed element. This solution changes the page layout and sets the innerHTML value to altHtml value. But interesting thing is that childNodes attribute retains the value from before the altHtml was set. This approach introduces another unknown and I am still interested in the first problem :)